# Form closes when clicking OK in a FolderBrowserDialog - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, path, folderbrowserdialog

I have a `Main` form and an `Options` form which starts when clicking on "Options" button in `Main` form. In the `Options` form, I have to select the work path. When clicking "OK" button in `Options` form to come back to the `Main` form, I want to check if the work path exists:

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(TextBoxWorkPath.Text) Then
   Main.WorkPath = TextBoxWorkPath.Text
Else
   MessageBox.Show("Please, enter a valid work path.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
   ButtonChangePath_Click(sender, New System.EventArgs())
End If
```

The code behind `ButtonChangePath_Click()` (in `Options` form) is:

```
Private Sub ButtonChangePath_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonChangePath.Click
        Dim fb = New FolderBrowserDialog
        fb.Description = "Select the destination folder for the output files:"
        If fb.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            TextBoxWorkPath.Text = fb.SelectedPath
        End If
End Sub
```

When I check if the work path exists, I open again the `FolderBrowserDialog` to select a correct path. But when I click "OK" the `Options` form closes and turn to `Main` form. If I click again in "Options" button, the work path is the same as before.

Comment: Check if your Options form has the `ButtonChangePath` in either the `AcceptButton` or the `CancelButton` properties.

Comment: No, it hasn't. Both are at `(nothing)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I fixed it. I had to place `Windows.Forms.DialogResult.None` in the If statement, in order to not to close the `Options` form.

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(TextBoxWorkPath.Text) Then
    Main.WorkPath = TextBoxWorkPath.Text
Else
    MsgBox("Please, enter a valid work path.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Attention!")
    Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.None
End If
```

So, when clicking on `OK` button, still stay in the `Options` form.